# Rails custom validation on 3 attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I want to create a validation that makes sure no other object in a table has the same combination of 3 attributes.

So say my code looks like the below:

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :color, :name, :height, :weight
end
```

I want to create a custom rails validation on the Dog class that makes sure there is no other dog in the database that has the same color, name, and weight. Is something like this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [validates_uniqueness_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :color, scope: [:name, :weight]
```